# PlatformException (ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL, The email address is badly formatted., null)

Tags: firebase, flutter, errorformat

i'm working in a project and using Firebase for authentication , so when i ran the code , it's return an Error called ( PlatformException(ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL, The email address is badly formatted., null) )
here's my code :
need your help to solve the problem.

````
class _RegistrationScreenState extends State<RegistrationScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String email;
  String password;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Hero(
              tag: 'logo',
              child: Container(
                height: 200.0,
                child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 48.0,
            ),
            TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              onChanged: (value) {
                email = value;
              },
              decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                  hintText: 'Enter your email'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            TextField(
              obscureText: true,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              onChanged: (value) {
                password = value;
              },
              decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                  hintText: 'Enter your password'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 24.0,
            ),
            RoundedButtons(
              colour: Colors.blueAccent,
              text: 'Register',
              onPressed: () async {
                try {
                  final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                      email: email, password: password);
                  if (newUser != null) {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
                  }
                } catch (e) {
                  print(e);
                }
           ```
````

Answer (score 0):

The error you are referring to is done with how to input your  `email address`.

correct way: `youremail@example.com`

for example: `test@gmail.com`